# Python3: Calculating the average... each total isn't being recognized

Tags: python, average

I've basically finished this program except for the last part where it is suppose to display
"The average grade is: "
and then it should add up each grade, then count each one, then divide
**the sum by the quantity.**
The issue I'm having is that my program is only taking the **last grade**, 70, and dividing 70 by **how many actual grades there are**, which is 3 grades.

**What the program should do is this:**

> Math score is 100
>
> Science score is 90
>
> Reading score is 70
>
> The average score is 86%

But instead, its saying
The average score is 23%

(Because it is doing 70/3 instead of 260/3).

I know this should be fixed with a loop, but I honestly have no idea where to start with fixing this.

This is the code I have so far:

```
gradesFile = open("grades.txt","r")

#Establishes the variables
total = 0
numberOfLines = 0
lines = 0
print('Here are your grades:','\n')

#Creates a loop that will print out each score
#Math score is 100
#Science score is 90
#and so on.
for line in gradesFile:
   numberOfLines += 1

   lines = line.strip()

   total = (gradesFile.readline())

   average = float(total) / (numberOfLines)

   print(lines + ' score is ' + total)

gradesFile.close

print('The average score is', average)
```

I'm super new to this.

Edit:
The grades.txt file looks like this. (1-7 meaning each line)

1 Math

2 100.0

3 Science

4 90.0

5 Reading

6 70.0

7

Comment: Provide us an example of the `gradesFile.txt` please

Comment: Can you share a sample of your input file `grades.txt ` ?

Comment: You're not saving your total, both total and average are rewritten at each iteration, declare it outside of the loop. (print both variables out or use a debugger to understand what's going on)

Comment: I posted the gradesFile.txt.

Comment: How would I declare it outside of the loop? Example?

Comment: after reading the line store it in the temporary and print it then add to the total

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```py
total = (gradesFile.readline())
```

with

```py
total += float(gradesFile.readline())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're consuming each grade & putting it into one variable "total". That's why only the last grade "70" is registered. You should add one more variable called sum right after the total, that you add the current total too. Then calculate the average using the sum.

As in:

```
total = int(gradesFile.readline()) # Need to convert string from read to int.

sum += total
```

average = sum / (numberOfLines)

Comment: If i do this, i get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sel/Documents/Module 6 Programs/program62.py", line 20, in <module>
    sum += total
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
Here are your grades: 
  File "C:/Users/Sel/Documents/Module 6 Programs/program62.py", line 20, in <module>

    sum = sum + total
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

Comment: Sum is a keyword. Which is why it's not a good variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes needed to be done.

1.change this line to accumulate the grades

```
total += float(gradesFile.readline())
```

2.Take calculating average statement outside the loop.

```
 average = float(total) / (numberOfLines)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sel/Documents/Module 6 Programs/program62.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(lines + ' score is ' + total)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Comment: You can use print("score is",total) or print(lines + 'score is' + str(total)) but remember your total now is accumulated over iterations. total is not the grade !!!

Comment: If i do print(lines + 'score is', str(total), i get this: Here are your grades: 

Math score is 100.0
Science score is 190.0
Reading score is 260.0
The average score is 86.66666666666667

Comment: So the average of 86 is right... but now the individual scores are wrong

Comment: What do you mean by total is not the grade?